# Performance issues with jms and spring integration. What is wrong with the following configuration?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messaging, spring-integration

I have a jms producer, which generates many messages per second, which are sent to amq persistent queue and are consumed by single consumer, which needs to process them sequentially. But it seems that the producer is much faster than the consumer and i am having performance and memory problems. Messages are fetched very very slowly and the consuming seems to happen on intervals (the consumer "asks" for messages in polling fashion, which is strange?!)

Basically everything happens with spring integration. Here is the configuration at the producer side. First stake messages come in stakesInMemoryChannel, from there, they are filtered throw the filteredStakesChannel and from there they are going into the jms queue (using executor so the sending will happen in separate thread)

```
    <bean id="stakesQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="${jms.stakes.queue.name}" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="stakesInMemoryChannel" />

    <int:channel id="filteredStakesChannel" >
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="stakeFilterService" class="cayetano.games.stake.StakeFilterService"/>

    <int:filter 
       input-channel="stakesInMemoryChannel"
       output-channel="filteredStakesChannel" 
       throw-exception-on-rejection="false"
       expression="true"/>

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="filteredStakesChannel" destination="stakesQueue" delivery-persistent="true" explicit-qos-enabled="true"  />

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="100" />
```

The other application is consuming the messages like this... The messages come in stakesInputChannel from the jms stakesQueue, after that they are routed to 2 separate channels, one persists the message and the other do some other stuff, lets call it "processing".

```
    <bean id="stakesQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="${jms.stakes.queue.name}" />
</bean>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    channel="stakesInputChannel" 
    destination="stakesQueue" 
    acknowledge="auto"
    concurrent-consumers="1"
    max-concurrent-consumers="1"
    />
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="stakesInputChannel" />
<int:channel id="persistStakesChannel" />
<int:channel id="processStakesChannel" />

<int:recipient-list-router 
        id="customRouter" 
        input-channel="stakesInputChannel" 
        timeout="3000" 
        ignore-send-failures="true" 
        apply-sequence="true"
        >
    <int:recipient channel="persistStakesChannel"/>
    <int:recipient channel="processStakesChannel"/>
</int:recipient-list-router> 


<bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
    <property name="queuePrefetch" value="${jms.broker.prefetch.policy}" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}" />     
            <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" /> 
            <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true" /> 
            <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "on intervals (the consumer "asks" for messages in polling fashion, which is strange".

The container threads might "look" like they're polling but they're not; they block in the AMQ client until a message arrives, or a timeout; when timeout, it immediately goes back into AMQ receive().

This configuration looks fine; with one thread, the rate of consumption will depend directly on what you are doing downstream of the router.

Comment: I created jms plan with jmeter, which sends messages directly to the activemq. I send a lot more messages - 1 each 20 milliseconds - and the consumer application is processing them perfectly without any delay... So, the problem must be in the producer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use a [PooledConnectionFactory](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.5.0/activemq-pool/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html/). This is recommended for use with Spring JmsTemplate and it pools Connection, Session, and MessageProducer instances so they can be returned after they are no longer in use.

I believe the "interval" behavior you are seeing on the consumer side is the consumer timing out.

Contrary to what Gary Russel said, `amq.receive()` does effectively poll the queue. The Spring config hides this, but messages are pulled out of a queue in basically a loop that calls receive on the consumer of the queue. The consumer of a queue has no way to know if a message is in the queue until it calls `receive()` to try to get the message.

This is the opposite with a topic, where you register a listener that performs actions when messages come in. Topics are an elegant solution, because you register a listener that processes the message.

With a Topic, you tell activemq what to do with the message, with a Queue, activemq just gives you the message when you ask for it.

Comment: Thanks i will change it with pooled connection factory...i will repeat what i said to Gary...
I created jms plan with jmeter, which sends messages directly to the activemq. I send a lot more messages - 1 each 20 milliseconds - and the consumer application is processing them perfectly without any delay... So, the problem must be in the producer configuration

Comment: "... does effectively poll the queue..." Yes; what I meant is that Spring does not "poll" the queue at intervals (e.g. every so many milliseconds). In effect, aside from a quick turnaround after a timeout, the thread is constantly sitting in amq.receive() waiting for a message to arrive. The timeout can be increased from the default, but it's needed so we can react to other things, such a stopping the container.

Comment: Ah yes, it doesn't poll it at interval, it is essentially the equivalent of a while(true) loop. Glad we are on the same page.